# Rails form button doesn't make params I am expecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I've been using radios with submit for my form but decided to switch to using normal buttons. But my form doesn't set up a usual `key: value` pair in my params as my `strong_params` are expecting.

Params I had and I am expecting in the new form:

```
{  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "_method"=>"patch", 
  "model_name" => { "event"=>"university_decided" }, 
  "university_decision"=>"university_accepted", 
  "controller"=>"unis", 
  "action"=>"update", 
  "id"=>"5"
}
```

But instead I get:

```
{  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "_method"=>"patch", 
  "event"=>"university_decided" , 
  "university_decision"=>"university_accepted", 
  "controller"=>"unis", 
  "action"=>"update", 
  "id"=>"5"
}
```

Original partial that worked with form outside the partial:

```
  %p.material-font-title
    %em What did the university decide?

  .radio
    = f.label :university_decision_university_accepted do
      = f.radio_button :university_decision, "university_accepted"
      Accepted
  .radio
    = f.label :university_decision_university_declined do
      = f.radio_button :university_decision, "university_declined"
      Declined
  = f.button "Mark university decided",
    value: "event_name",
    name: "event",
    class: "btn btn-ghost-info"
```

Here is my new form inside a partial:

```
= form_for model_name do |f|
  = hidden_field_tag "event", "event_name"

  %p.material-font-title
    %em What did the university decide?

  = f.button "Accepted",
    value: "university_accepted",
    name: "university_decision",
    class: "btn btn-default"
```

which is being called from Controller view:

```
 = render "#{path}/university_decision", model_name: @model
```

Comment: ```form_for model_name``` should be ```form_for <an instance/object of model>```

Comment: It is, this a partial and I pass model object in there

Comment: Have you created namespaced routes for this model in routes.rb

Comment: what are you expecting in the params? if its `event`, it will not come as model param because you have it as `tag`

Comment: No, event is working as I want it. My problem is with `{university_decision: "university_accepted"` which should be inside `model_name:`, but it's not

Comment: @Vimsha I've updated the question with exact params I had and the new ones I am getting now

Comment: You mentioned that event was fine and as per your new edit you are expecting change in event hash...Is that a typo in your edit...

Comment: Can you post how the routes are written for this model. That actually matters. Incase if that is under a namespace in routes.rb please post the name of namespace as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a very simple solution, I've forgotten that I can define nested names. So button will look like this to make my params look correctly:

```
  = f.button "Accepted",
    value: "university_accepted",
    name: "model_name[university_decision]",
    class: "btn btn-default"
```